# Static initialization of openCV in android is not working

Tags: android, opencv, apk

I'm trying to add openCV libraries into an Android project to use it in the static initialization way but when I build the application the openCV libraries are not added to the apk.

I put them under the root directory source (called app in Android Studio) in a folder called libs, and then I nested a folder for every target: armeabi, x86, etc.

Do I need to do something else?anybody knows why they are not being added to the apk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem. I just had to put the .so files under src/main/jniLibs and they are added to the apk when bulding. Easier than expected :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the Android NDK? Because I think OpenCV is native C/C++ code so you need the NDK in order to accommodate the library into your project.